# python web scrape how to separate the results by comma

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

the web page I'm scraping is https://www.dassaultfalcon.com/en/Support/worldwide-presence/Pages/Service-Network-List.aspx?Category=Authorized%2bService%2bCenters

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
info = []
url = 'https://www.dassaultfalcon.com/en/Support/worldwide-presence/Pages/Service-Network-List.aspx?Category=Authorized%2bService%2bCenters'
r = requests.get(url,headers = header)
soup = bs4(r.text,'html.parser')
main = soup.find('div',class_='df-article')
part = main.find_all('section',class_='wrapper-list-network')
for i in range(len(part)):
    partin = part[i].find_all('div',class_='network-item')
    for j in range(len(partin)):
        i1 = {}
        if i == 0:
            i1['district'] = 'Europe' 
        elif i ==1:
            i1['district'] = 'North America'
        elif i ==2:
            i1['district'] = 'Pacific Rim'
        elif i==3:
            i1['district'] = 'Africa'
        elif i==4:
            i1['district'] = 'Central & South America'
        else:
            i1['district'] = 'Middle East'
        i1['name'] = partin[j].find('h2').text.strip()
        i1['mailing and address'] = partin[j].find('div',class_='inner_network_item_col mailing').text.strip().split('\n')[2:]
        i1['phone numbers'] = partin[j].find('div',class_='inner_network_item_col phonenumber').text.strip().split('\n')[2:]
        i1['models concerned'] = partin[j].find('div',class_='inner_network_item_col models').text.strip().split('\n')[1:]
        info.append(i1)
```

they all worked well except for the phone and models, there's no comma or space between each and some of the phone number got strange code like \u200b, \xa, at the start or end of the phone number. I will show two of the result below

```
[{'district': 'Europe',
  'name': 'AMAC AEROSPACE TURKEY A.S.',
  'mailing and address': ['IDTM A2 Blok Kat: 11 No: 35234149 YesilkoyIstanbulTURKEY'],
  'phone numbers': ['AOG Tel: +90 533 035 49 49Office: +90 212 463 03 00Fax: +90 212 465 82 82\u200b'],
  'models concerned': ['Falcon 2000Falcon 2000DXFalcon 2000EX EASyFalcon 2000LXFalcon 2000LXSFalcon 2000SFalcon 900DXFalcon 900EX EASyFalcon 900LXFalcon 7XFalcon 8XFalcon 900B']}
```

```
{'district': 'Europe',
  'name': 'Dassault Satellite Service Station — Roma, Italy',
  'mailing and address': ['Dassault Satellite Service StationAeroporto CiampinoAeronautica MilitareRome 00040\xa0ITALY'],
  'phone numbers': ['Phone:\xa0+39 6 79 34 95 11'],
  'models concerned': ['Falcon 50Falcon 50EXFalcon 7XFalcon 8XFalcon 900Falcon 900EXFalcon 900EX EASyFalcon 900LXFalcon 2000Falcon 2000DXFalcon 2000EXFalcon 2000EX EASyFalcon 2000LXFalcon 2000LXSFalcon 2000S']}
```

My desired output will be just add comma before each phone number and model

```
[{'district': 'Europe',
  'name': 'AMAC AEROSPACE TURKEY A.S.',
  'mailing and address': ['IDTM A2 Blok Kat: 11 No: 35234149 YesilkoyIstanbulTURKEY'],
  'phone numbers': ['AOG Tel: +90 533 035 49 49,Office: +90 212 463 03 00,Fax: +90 212 465 82 82'],
  'models concerned': ['Falcon 2000,Falcon 2000DX,Falcon 2000EX EASy,Falcon 2000LX,Falcon 2000LXS,Falcon 2000S,Falcon 900DX,Falcon 900EX EASy,Falcon 900LX,Falcon 7X,Falcon 8X,Falcon 900B']}
```

Comment: what is your desired output please share it!

Comment: `\xa0` and `\u200b` is a different type of space, just google them and you will see. You can replace them with `.replace('\xa0', ' ')`

Comment: @dewinterbinich check below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `get_text()` method

```
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4(r.text,'lxml')
main_data=soup.find("div",class_="network-item")

str1=[main_data.find("div",class_="inner_network_item_col models").find_all("ul")[0].get_text(strip=True,separator=",")]
str1
```

Output:

```
['Falcon 2000,Falcon 2000DX,Falcon 2000EX EASy,Falcon 2000LX,Falcon 2000LXS,Falcon 2000S,Falcon 900DX,Falcon 900EX EASy,Falcon 900LX,Falcon 7X,Falcon 8X,Falcon 900B']
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pp

region = {}


def main(url):
    params = {
        'Category': 'Authorized Service Centers'
    }
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    for i in soup.select('.r-title'):
        region[i.text] = []
        for x in i.find_next('section').select('.network-item'):
            region[i.text].append({
                'name': x.h2.text,
                'Address': list(x.select_one('div[class^=ExternalClass]').stripped_strings),
                'Phone': list(x.select('div[class^=ExternalClass]')[1].stripped_strings),
                'Models': [x.text for x in soup.select('.inner_network_item_col ul li')]
            })


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('https://www.dassaultfalcon.com/en/Support/worldwide-presence/Pages/Service-Network-List.aspx')
    pp(region)
```